# outlook for android "no app installed to open this", but it's just a link

Tags: android, html, email, outlook, html-email

I have an automated system that sends out HTML emails. The link in the email works fine on the desktop version of outlook. But when I try and open it in the android version of outlook, it's predicated by "render://init-bundle/" and then my url follows like "render://init-bundle/www.website.com".

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a full link i.e. including the https:// or http:// protocol at the start of the href.